# horizontal scrolling positioning div

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling

I am super new to jquery and I am trying to create a horizontal scrolling site so that when you click the links on the navbar it scrolls the content to the center of the browser window. At the moment I have it scrolling with the code below but it always positions the content to the left of the screen. Is there a way to offset it so the content scolls to the center?

```
$(function() {
$('ul.nav a').bind('click',function(event){
    var $anchor = $(this);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
    }, 1000);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

});

HTML:

```
<div id="navbar">


    <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#slide1">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide2">Parties</a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide3">Video</a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide4">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="slide one" id="slide1">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
width:16000px;
height:552px;

}
.slide {

height:552px;
width:1000px;
/*top: 50%;*/
left: 50%;
margin-top: 100px;
margin-left: -500px;
position:absolute;


}   

.one {

background-image:url(../images/background.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document

Change .bind() to .on() or .click().

I'm not 100% sure what are you trying to achieve, i found a tutorial how to create a horisontal scroll: http://gazpo.com/2012/03/horizontal-content-scroll/.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm trying to create something like this: http://jolliesbarn.co.uk/   the page scrolls horizontally when clicking on the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example and try to implemet it in your horizontal scroll

**http://jsfiddle.net/nxcfX/**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#MyList li:nth-child(1)").click(function(){
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 100 }, 600);
   });
   $("#MyList li:nth-child(2)").click(function(){
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 300 }, 600);
   });
   $("#MyList li:nth-child(3)").click(function(){
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 500 }, 600);
   });
   $("#MyList li:nth-child(4)").click(function(){
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 900 }, 600);
   });
});
```